# boost-beast specify source endpoint to bind to

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm using boost::beast for TCP connections, with an async flow. I'm wondering what the most appropriate way is to specify the source IP/port to bind to.

I illustrate one attempt below,

```
        template <typename Stream, typename Endpoints, typename Handler>
        static void connect(Stream& stream, const Endpoints& endpoints, Handler handler) {
            auto& tcpStream = beast::get_lowest_layer(stream);
            tcpStream.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(10));

            // one attempt.
            tcpStream.socket().open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
            tcpStream.socket().bind( boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 0));

            tcpStream.async_connect(
                endpoints,
                [&stream, handler](const auto ec, const auto&){ onConnect(stream, ec, handler); }
            );
        }
```

This appears to work fine for one end-point (but is perhaps non-idiomatic?), but presumably the socket gets opened and closed repeatedly on failure in case of an end-point sequence as in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__basic_stream/async_connect/overload2.html - and then this wouldn't behave correctly.

Is there a more idiomatic approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but presumably the socket gets opened and closed repeatedly on failure

I was skeptical. The documentation specifically states:

- The underlying socket is automatically opened if needed.
- An automatically opened **socket is not returned to the closed state upon failure**

It seems fair to expect that if the socket was already open, it will also not be returned to the closed state.

However, you're right to smell the opportunity for a problem here. And I went to check.

## The Surprise

Indeed, the `bind` doesn't appear to hold, even when there's a single endpoint, but it's using the endpoint-sequence overload. Here's a comprehensive demonstration:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core/tcp_stream.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

auto fake_dns_result() {
    tcp::endpoint eps[]{
        {{}, 7878}, // not available
        {{}, 6767}, // running netcat
    };
    return tcp::resolver::results_type::create( //
        std::begin(eps), std::end(eps), "localhost", "dummysvc");
}

void test(tcp::endpoint local_ep) {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    auto endpoints = fake_dns_result();
   
    boost::beast::tcp_stream s(ioc);

    s.socket().open(tcp::v4());
    s.socket().bind(local_ep);

    auto log = [&s, local_ep](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint const& next) {
        std::cout << ec.message() << " next:" << next << " "
                  << (s.socket().is_open() ? "open" : "closed")
                  << " bound:" << s.socket().local_endpoint()
                  << std::endl;
        return true;
    };

    s.async_connect(endpoints, log, [&s](auto ec, const auto& /*ep*/) {
        std::cout << " --> Final " << ec.message() << " local "
                  << s.socket().local_endpoint() << " to "
                  << s.socket().remote_endpoint() << "\n\n";
    });

    ioc.run();
}

int main() {
    using A = asio::ip::address_v4;
    test({});                          // 0.0.0.0:0
    test({A::loopback(), 0});          // 127.0.0.1:0
    test({A{{127, 0, 0, 42}}, 0});     // 127.0.0.1:0
    test({A{{192, 168, 50, 225}}, 0}); // 192.168.50.225:0
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0c2cb1e3d3b88fd)**:

```
Success next:0.0.0.0:7878 open bound:0.0.0.0:36700
Connection refused next:0.0.0.0:6767 open bound:127.0.0.1:35126
 --> Final Success local 127.0.0.1:59672 to 127.0.0.1:6767

Success next:0.0.0.0:7878 open bound:127.0.0.1:51845
Connection refused next:0.0.0.0:6767 open bound:127.0.0.1:35130
 --> Final Success local 127.0.0.1:59676 to 127.0.0.1:6767

Success next:0.0.0.0:7878 open bound:127.0.0.42:37227
Connection refused next:0.0.0.0:6767 open bound:127.0.0.1:35134
 --> Final Success local 127.0.0.1:59680 to 127.0.0.1:6767

Success next:0.0.0.0:7878 open bound:173.203.57.63:49499
Connection refused next:0.0.0.0:6767 open bound:127.0.0.1:35138
 --> Final Success local 127.0.0.1:59684 to 127.0.0.1:6767
```

As you suggested, the bound endpoint is *not* honoured. Even moving the `bind` into the connection condition doesn't help:

```
s.socket().open(tcp::v4());

auto log = [&s, local_ep](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint const& next) {
    std::cout << ec.message() << " next:" << next << " "
              << (s.socket().is_open() ? "open" : "closed")
              << " bound:" << s.socket().local_endpoint()
              << std::endl;
    s.socket().bind(local_ep);
    return true;
};
```

Still prints the same

```
Success next:0.0.0.0:7878 open bound:173.203.57.63:49499
Connection refused next:0.0.0.0:6767 open bound:127.0.0.1:35138
 --> Final Success local 127.0.0.1:59684 to 127.0.0.1:6767
```

### Stripping The Beast

Reviewing the implementation, it looks like `asio::[async_]connect` should have the exact same behaviour, because Beast only adds the timeout logic. Let's reduce: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3154ab094edf5a5).

As expected, same output. On to reviewing the Asio implementation.

### Stripping The Async

Just to simplify the review, let's also check the synchronous connect behaves the same:

```
error_code ec;
/*auto ep =*/ asio::connect(s, endpoints, log, ec);

std::cout << " --> Final " << ec.message() << " local "
          << s.local_endpoint() << " to " << s.remote_endpoint() << "\n\n";
```

Still the same: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9932d8dfbb3e5391)

### The Culprit

Indeed, the implementation of the range-connect in Asio looks like this:

```
  for (Iterator iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter)
  {
    iter = (detail::call_connect_condition(connect_condition, ec, iter, end));
    if (iter != end)
    {
      s.close(ec);
      s.connect(*iter, ec);
      if (!ec)
        return iter;
    }
    else
      break;
  }
```

It follows that it will be impossible to get the required behavior on range-connect, short of

- creating your own socket type that binds on open.
- writing your own range-connect operation that uses a local endpoint